# Notepad++ show open files on the left

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++, is there a way to show the list of files that are currently open in a list on the left instead of using the default tab-view?

(I'd like it to resemble the way TextPad shows the files that are currently open.)

I'm NOT referring to an Explorer which will allow me to open new files, I just don't like the tabs on top when many files are opened.

Comment: you know you can change your selected answer?  If you do I would suggest leaving a comment for the one that used to be the selected answer so they know why their status changed :^)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Settings > Preferences > tab General > Document List Panel > check Show

Credit to anonymous coward

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for - that puts the tabbar vertical but the name of the documents too. I'd like the document names op appear horizontal, but on the left. Eg what I have with the "snippets" on the left.

Comment: The Window Manager plugin seems exactly what I was looking for ! thx!

Comment: The links are broken.

Comment: I think the Window Manager plugin has now been integrated into Notepad++ (or at least the same functionality has). In Preferences -> General, check "Show" in the "Document List Panel" area.

EDIT: And now I see that the next answer (which has many more votes) already explained this.

Comment: Wrong answer and links are broken. Correct answer is by @anonymous coward

Comment: unfortunately moving to the left cause, all text on tabs are flipped :( Is it option similar to windows belt, when I set it vertically on the left or right, all working application are displayer horizontally on vertical belt. Is it possible in n++ ?

Answer (score 161):

Settings > Preferences > tab General > Document List Panel > check Show

Comment: I don't have a "document switcher" part on my general-tab in preferences... ?

Comment: I found the "document switcher" in the Misc tab under preferences. But it's already ticked, and nothing appears on the left...

Comment: Argl, was going to post this one as an additional answer because the accepted one did not do it for me, only to scroll down and already see it. Damn "sorting by votes" that does not do what it sais...

Answer (score 31):

In Notepad++ v8.1.4, which is considerably newer than the versions that were discussed above, there is a "Document List" button that lets you show or hide the document list.

[image: "Document List" button]

Comment: It's about time I get to this solution! There are 8 to 10 **identical** solutions above all adressing an outdated version... Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. For the newer versions of Notepad++ this is the one that works. All other answers address the problem in the older versions only, I guess.

Answer (score 22):

In Notepad++ 6.4.5
Settings->Preferences->General->Document List Panel-> check "Show"

Comment: Thanks! I had already enabled this, but had accidentally closed the docked panel and couldn't for the life of me find the setting to get it back! Unfortunately that is a bit of a problem... if you do close the panel you seem to have to drill down in Settings and uncheck/check  the "Show" box in order to get it back!? Is there really no quicker way, once it is already enabled?

Comment: @w3dk strange indeed that there is *still* no shortcut, icon, or "view" menu entry for this panel. Same thing for favorites. From what i can tell, the only way to turn that on/off is via the toolbar icon.

Comment: This is my preferred way to list the files, too, but for the life of me I can not understand why this is not under the View menu.

Answer (score 18):

I found *Document Switcher* in General tab in prefs. Then I clicked the *Show* checkbox and that did the trick.

Make sure you have the latest `Notepad++` version.

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be a bug in Notepad++.

TLDR;
Open `Settings -> Preferences -> General -> Document List Panel`.
If `[x] Show` is already marked, Uncheck it, then re-Check it.
You should see the panel re-appear.
Click 'Close" to re-save the setting.

Even though you never changed this setting, (and it *looks* like your preferences are just as you left them)...
if you ever click the [x] at the top of the panel that shows "Folder as Workspaces" or "Document List", aka "Doc Switcher", internally the app acts as though this setting was turned off (but also still shows the checkmark when you open up Preferences).

---

If you have "Show Document List" checked in settings, then via the View Menu, or the Toolbar Menu, choose "Folder as Workspace", you cannot easily switch back to the "Open Documents" list (aka "Show Document List):

If you close "Doc Switcher" (the heading at the top of the 
Folder as Document Space" tab), it closes the tab completely. If you re-enable "Folder as Document Space", the tiny tab at the bottom of that space no longer shows the tiny tab that previously could be used to switch between "Folder as Workspace" and "open documents".

In this case, the only way to turn it back on, is to go back into Preferences. The thing is, the setting controlling visibility of the "Open Files List" is already "checked" indicating it's turned on already.

Just Uncheck it, then re-check it, and "Save Settings".

There are numerous things going on here that should be cleaned up in Notepad++ around this issue.
1) Consistent Naming for "Document List Panel". Settings calls it "Document List Panel; Panel Title calls it 'Doc Switcher".

2) Document List Panel should be an option under the View Menu (just as "Folder as Workspace" is).

3) Document List Panel should be an item in the toolbar just as "Folder as Workspace" is.

4)  Consistent Naming between "Document List Panel" and "Folder as Workspace". One calls it a panel, the other does not.

5) Closing "Folder as Workspace" via the "x" at the top of its panel, should not *silently* also close the "Doc Switcher" (aka "Show Document List", ie "Open Documents Panel").

6) Since it closes the whole panel, it should internally uncheck the "Show Documents List" option in the Settings Preferences -> General -> Document List Panel -> [x] Show

7) Perhaps the "Doc Switcher"/"Folder as Workspace" label at the top of the panel should be renamed to indicate that closing it, closes the *whole panel*, not *just* currently highlighted tab within the panel.
*IF* Only "Document as Workspace" *or* "Doc Switcher" (aka Document as List") is the *only* tab in that panel, the point is moot.  But when both tabs there (the tabs are at the bottom of the panel), the behavior is unexpected, and even inconsistent. Side effects of closing, what looks like the *tab* title* is unexpected: it actually closes the panel, and one of the "tab views" is difficult to get back.

8) The tabs which are at the bottom of the panel, should be moved to just under the Panel Title/Active Tab kludge which is talked about above.

9) If there is space, The inactive tab should also show its title, rather than be reduced to an icon.
This is especially true in its present location at the bottom of the panel, and because in the current kludge, the active panel shows its title both at the panel title at the top, and the active tab a the bottom. Weird, and confusing.
It is unclear what the other tab is, given the current setup, and strangely linked, yet inconsistent behavior of the current setup.

*there really ought to be an option in the View Menu for "Open Documents" just as there is one for "Folder as Workspace".  But there is not.*

`The Settings -> Preferences -> General -> View Document List -> [x] Show` is broken if the "Doc Switcher" panel ever gets closed.  In the case of closure, the app behaves as though the setting has been unchecked, but upon opening the dialog, it shows the setting as still marked.  The way to re-enable" the setting is to uncheck, then re-check it, and Close the Preferences dialog.
The Doc Switcher panel holds "Folder as Workspace" tab *and* "Folder as Workspace" tabs.  But, if the "Folder as Workspace" tab is highlighted, it shows the title of that tab, which implies that clicking the "x" would close that *tab*, not the whole panel.

Conversely, the "Document List" tab is labeled as "Doc Switcher", rather than "Document List".  So there is confusion as to what that "tab" is supposed to refer do. And since the title for that panel = tab name, closing the panel, makes it look as though we should be looking for "Doc Switcher" setting somewhere in the View Menu, or Settings-Preferences Panel.  It is simply confusing, unclear what's going on.

*Honestly, Better names for those two settings would be appreciated, though, probably not possible with so many current users.*

Distinction between the Panel, and the "tabs" or types of information that can appear within the panel *NEEDS* to be separated out.  They need to be labeled distinctly within the panel, and within both the View Menu, and the Settings-Preferences Window.  The behavior between these various settings *NEEDS* to be unified between: View menu options, Toolbar options, Settings -Preferences, and the actions taken inside this "Doc Switcher" panel, including title for the panel, whether "tabs" are shown in the panel, the title of said tabs, matching the tab title to the type of listing that tab displays, and *what happens when clicking on the "x" button on the panel title. Oh, and synching the behavior of clicking on that "x" button to the Settings in Preferences (as well as options in View menu and the toolbar - this part seems to the only piece that currently *does* work as expected).

Finally, Show Document List *should* be added as a View menu option, and toolbar option!

Answer (score 5):

Settings > Preferences > General > **Document Panel List** > [ ] Show (checkbox).

The **Document Panel List** seems to get disabled somehow when moving the Project Panel or other interface panels around. Odd, that this config/option is not arranged with:

- View > Document Map
- View > Project

Comment: View > Document list

Answer (score 5):

For those so inclined, a useful feature (relative to this question) is to use the Document switcher (Ctrl+TAB).  You can tab-through or mouse click to select from your open documents.  In doing this, no static screen real-estate will be consumed.  Enjoy.

Comment: i was looking for this thanks. i have tons of files open and this gives a nice another way to switch between files

Answer (score 5):

to enable Document List panel in left plz click button attached in image[image]

Comment: This appears to duplicate the answer given four weeks ago by @Alan. Whilst answering questions here is good, repeating an existing answer is not useful. New answers to old questions should give new information and new insights into the problem and its solution.

Answer (score 3):

Settings > Preferences > General > Tab Bar > Vertical

This moves the document tab to a thin vertical strip on the left. As a result, very little real estate is wasted at the bottom left, below the document tab.

In contrast, lots of precious real estate is left empty at the bottom left when you turn on Document Switcher a.k.a. Document List Panel.

Particularly important to laptops with limited screens.

Answer (score 2):

The answers reflecting "Document List Panel" are correct (but this may be enabled in different locations or unvailable depending on version.) 7.2.2 has it in Settings->Preferences->General (lower left of dialog)

**Another simple method** which works fairly well: **Alt-W W** or **Alt-W Alt-W** (both work) to **bring up the (full) "Windows" list dialog** where you can:

- Activate (Switch windows)
- Close
- Save (but this seems to be broken through version 7.2.2)

The file list is NOT sorted by default (nor configurable) and doesn't have either "acceleration" for finding files nor is there an apparent way to get the sort by keyboard (clicking on the column header does do a sort by column but required using the mouse of course.)

Alt W W is pretty reasonable and fairly mnemonic.  Also if you only have a few file open (<10 then the full list will show immediately as the "Window menu" down with JUST the "Alt-W".

(I habitually keep many files open so having a quick switcher matters.)

Another useful but limited trick:  Just do a file open of the file you want to switch to -- if it is open then the tab will come to focus.  This is however a not fully satisfying method of switching for me.

Comment: Just in case you happen to use it, with Listary you can type the name of the file and it will autocomplete in that window list

Answer (score 1):

View > Document List

In the new version of Notepad++ "Document List" option is placed under the View menu. Also to view the document structure we can enable the "Document Map" option.

Answer (score 0):

I too suffered with this, and to finally answer the question of how to dock the document list on the left.

You open the document list, drag the window to the left using the top ribbon and down to the bottom of the window and it will doc on the left instead of the top.

Version 8.5.2

Good luck.