# how to enable document list panel in latest notepad++ editor?

Tags: notepad++

I have just updated to notepad++ V 8.1.3 and it no longer has the option to display open files in left panel.

How to  Enable the Document List Panel  again?  I looked at this question [notepad-show-open-files-on-the-left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108193/notepad-show-open-files-on-the-left) also, but they all say the same thing

`Settings > Preferences > tab General > Document List Panel > check Show`

Which is no longer there in version 8.1.3 on windows 10

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Please do this for the new Notepad++

**1.** Go to **View** and select **Document List**

[image]

**2.** You got your document list

[image]

My version is the same as yours (but 64 bit)

[image]